# How to connect your ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC web application to Active Directory?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, roles

I am building a web application for a client, where I will have to set it up on their Windows Server via IIS. I will have to integrate their base of users into my application via Active Directory (not Azure Active Directory). I have already included Windows authentication into my application and it seems to work on my local computer.

What I want to know is:

- How to change the login prompt into my custom login page?
- How to change the username of the authenticated user (right now when I sign in, I have to write down the name of the device and the name of the user. for example: _device/_user). What I want is for the user to simply be able to only write their username, not device name.
- How to manage the access of the users, and how to add roles to them inside the application. Since the user is signed In. I now want to know how do I assign this user a certain role, so I can restrict access to certain pages based on that.

I have been looking through some documentation but not much is mentioned about Active Directory integration or the questions that I have listed above.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps;

1. You need to have System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement references in your project, if you want to access AD.
2. Configure AD name and AD Organizational Units in appsettings.js `ActiveDirectory": { "ActiveDirectoryDomainName": "Your Domain", "ActiveDirectoryOrganizationalUnits": "Your AD units" }`
3. In your class method:

   [image: AD Login]
4. Fill your user object with AD values like userPrincipal.EmailAddress,userPrincipal.GivenName,userPrincipal.Guid.Value and etc.
5. If you want to manage users with roles, then take the GUID from AD (userPrincipal.Guid.Value) and store it another table and map that GIUD with required roles.

Note: If you can share some images and codes

Comment: Thank you. Using System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement has made it pretty simple to connect to Active Directory and extract needed data. Since I made a custom Login, I am not using Windows authentication anymore. User simply writes their username and password, which I check In the Active directory. Afterwards I check In Identity table if User has been Added to Application (in the Identity table I've added the GUID) .Based on the Identity table I can also get user Role for each user.

Comment: Perfect. Glad it helped you :)